# Can you connect an outdoor GFCI to an indoor outlet using 14 g wire if it is a 20 amp circuit? The GFCI will be used for a sump pump only

Tags: wiring, gfci

I am tapping off a indoor outlet on a 20 amp line with 12 g wiring to an outdoor gfi. The wiring from the gfi is already wired by the previous owner via 14 g wire through conduit to an outlet that will be used for a sump pump. Do I have to replace the 14 g wiring with 12g?

Comment: the wire will burn in hell before the 20 amp even flinches

Comment: The good news is that if you have conduit as stated then you can just swap the 14 AWG for 12 AWG and be done very easily. If it is actually cable then it might be harder to replace.

Comment: Unfortunately if there is any 14 AWG wire in the circuit, it is a 15A circuit now.